# How to get data from service in widget without binding to it?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am writing application that has service that provides real time data to subscribers via remote callback mechanism. Now I wanted to add a widget that visualizes essential part of this data but got error: "IntentReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services". So what's the right way to get data from that service?

Comment: Do you mean a app widget or a normal widget?

Comment: Yes, I mean App Widget. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution - it must be not widget connecting to service, but service updating a widget on request. It is well explained here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part4